# Appending Image Name that can show pop up when clicked

Tags: jquery, image, popup

I am trying to append image name into a table cell. The image name (E.g. xxx.jpg), when clicked will show a pop up of the image, and can be closed.

Is this possible using Jquery alone?

*Assume the directory for my image is 'http://myserver/project/images/'*

```js
function  myfunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
  
        if(arr.length == 0){
        alert("Zero result found!");            
        }

        else if (arr[0].count != 0){                       
                                          
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  
$("#questiondisplay").append("<tr><td>" + arr[i].question_id + "</td><td>" + arr[i].question + "</td><td class='my_image'>" + arr[i].image + "</td></tr>");
  
        }}}
                 
        $('.my_image').click(function(){
window.open(path+$(this).html(),null, "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
});
```

```html
<div id="questiondisplayarea">

  <table data-role="table" id="questiontable">
                        
       <tbody id="questiondisplay">
       </tbody>

  </table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: probably this is what you're looking for http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this using JQuery:

1- On `click` event on the required element you can run  `window.open()`.

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/nsp0kyd7/)

Comment: Hi Armani, I added a class to the td tag containing the appended image name. And included the window.open() function. However, the image name when clicked does not run. I had edited my question to show how does the current codes look like.

Comment: Update: I had figured out how does your code works and applied it to my codes! Thumbs up for your fiddle Miss Armani!

Comment: sorry I saw your question too late but happy that you solved it :)